# swift: ContainerView correct action

Tags: ios, swift

I have `firstViewController` and `secondViewController`. I want to elements from the `secondViewController` to overlap the `firstViewController` (but should be `firstViewController` visible like background). I use `containerView` for this with clear color. In storyboard I press hidden for `containerView` and in `firstViewController.swift` I have action - `containerView.isHidden = false`.

question: Is this correct `containerView` using? I do not really like that at `firstViewController` start data from `secondViewController` also loading. Maybe in my action I should call `secondViewController` another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not totally clear on what effect you are trying to achieve.  So I tell you want I sometimes do for overlapping views:

(Like your secondViewController) is displayed as a modal.  So in (like your firstViewController), on a specific action:

```
        let vc = secondViewController()
        vc.dialogWindow.layer.masksToBounds = true
        vc.dialogWindow.borderWidth = 3
        vc.dialogWindow.borderColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.75)
        vc.isModalInPopover = true
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

That way the secondViewController is presented over the firstViewController.  To close it, it calls:

```
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Maybe you'll want to adjust the properties.